# Firefox Addon: XMLHttpRequest minor bug reading JSON

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon

I have noticed that *XMLHttpRequest* in my Firefox addon logs an error processing *xyz.json* if content is an array.
The error does not halt the execution (hence a minor bug)

Example of *xyz.json*:

```
[
  "string1",
  "string2",
  "string3"
]
```

Although above is a valid JSON, *XMLHttpRequest* logs a syntax error at **[**

It is possible to avoid the error logging by setting *responseType* to *'text'*.

Is this limited to Firefox Addon or Firefox or JavaScript in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox will consult the response MIME type to see if the response should be parsed as XML. Reading some `file:`, `chrome:`, `resource:`, etc. that does not provide a response MIME type will make XHR default to XML (backwards-compatibility; after all the XML is right in the name), and attempt to parse it to provide `.responseXML`. This will of course fail if the file does not contain XML, and hence the warning.

Use [`.overrideMimeType()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#overrideMimeType%28%29) to provide an explicit proper MIME type, or just `text/plain` if in doubt, to stop XHR from attempting to parse data as XML, and the message will go away.

Comment: Thanks Nils. I thought the default was string [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) but it seems it is not for local `file:/chrome:/resource:`:)